# Class 'Google_Client' not found

Tags: php, yii2

I have create a component :

```
<?php
    namespace common\components;
    use Google_Client;
    use Google_Service_Gmail;
    use Yii;
    use yii\base\ErrorException;
    use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
    use yii\base\Component;

    use yii\rest\ActiveController;
    use linslin\yii2\curl;



    class SocialLogin extends Component {
      public $GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;
      public $FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID;
      public $GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID_IOS;




      public function getGoogleUser($id_token,$device)
      {
            $clientID=$this->GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID;

            if($device=="ios")
            $clientID=$this->GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID_IOS;

            $client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $clientID]);
            $payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
            if ($payload) {
                    // my code
            }

        }    

   }
```

Its working fine on local but on live server i'm getting following error :

> message": "Class 'Google_Client' not found",

What will be the issue ?

Comment: Have you installed the required (composer) packages?

Comment: Did you require the composer autoload.php?

Comment: Yes i have uploaded all vendor files and folders on live

Comment: And installed via composer

Comment: Could you show your package list in this Yii2 project via `composer show`?

Comment: check for comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510014/use-google-drive-api-in-laravel-5/54901166#54901166

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue. `The issue was PHP version`, it was PHP 7 on my local machine and on server it was 5.6 then I have updated the PHP version and all problems are gone.

Answer (score 2):

Include below code in composer.json file in your root directory.

```
 {
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0"
      }
   }
```

And then run command:  *composer update*

This will create a folder google in your vendor directory at root level. Inside this google folder there are subfolders of apiclient, apiclient-services and auth.

Comment: You can generate the composer.json file with `composer require google/apiclient`.  At time of writing, it will give you version `"^2.12"`.

Answer (score 2):

check the file composer.json

and add "vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google" in classmap array if not exist.

and run `composer dump-autoload`

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google"
        ]
}
```

Comment: The file/folder doesnt even exist. Where can I download it?

Comment: @djack109: run this command in the command line: composer require google/apiclient

Answer (score 1):

If you already required the composer autoload.php and require the `google/apiclient` composer package, you can search `vendor/composer/autoload_static.php` for:

```
'Google_' => 
    array (
        0 => __DIR__ . '/..' . '/google/apiclient/src',
    ),
```

This is `google/apiclient` PSR-0 map, if you don't find it or the path is wrong, it means that the `google/apiclient` package is not install correctly.

Hope this could help you.

Comment: I found that exactly entry. Though I had include 7 uses in my component file in order to work. I don't have much time for this google task and I wonder if there isn't a use Google/*; or something.