# Rest API call : How to connect Google Drive with laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

Currently working with AWS with laravel 5, Need to add google drive to my laravel project, how to connect to google drive to upload and view files for users.

I am tried following sample but getting login required error. how to get access_token before upload file?

```
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId('abc.apps.googleusercontent.com');
    $client->setClientSecret('abc');
    $client->setRedirectUri('abc');
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'));

    if (isset($_GET['code']) || (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token'])) 
    {
        if (isset($_GET['code'])){

            $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        }
        else
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

            $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

            $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
            $file->setDescription('image');
            $file->setMimeType('image/png');

            $data = file_get_contents(public_path('images\log.png');
            $createdFile = $service->files->create($file, array(
                        'data' => $data,
                        'mimeType' => 'image/png',
                        'uploadType' => 'multipart'
                    ));

            return $createdFile;

 } else {
      $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
      header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
      exit();
 }
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ivanvermeyen/cc7c59c185daad9d4e7cb8c661d7b89b#file-readme-md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use google service account to avoid login or access token.
2. attache service account json file to google client API (create key in service account page)
3. upload file to google drive and get file id
4. use file id to access your file in the browser

Example :
Using two functions to create and view file

```
public function uploadTogoogleDrive(){
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig(public_path('service_account.json'));
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'));
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
        'name' => 'DefaltReport.pdf'));
    $content = file_get_contents(public_path('reports\DefaltReport.pdf'));
    $file = $service->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
        'data' => $content,
        'mimeType' => 'application/pdf',
        'uploadType' => 'multipart',
        'fields' => 'id'));
    printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id); // Your file id

}

public function viewGoogleDriveFile(){

    $fileId = $_GET['fileId'];
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig(public_path('service_account.json'));
    $client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'));
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    $response = $service->files->get($fileId, array(
        'alt' => 'media' ));
    header('Content-type:application/pdf');
    echo $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can check this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778296/use-google-drive-api-with-laravel). It points out how to login and file upload on google drive.

Here is the code from github specified in the post.

```
<?php
/*
 * Copyright 2011 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
include_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
include_once "templates/base.php";
echo pageHeader("File Upload - Uploading a large file");
/*************************************************
 * Ensure you've downloaded your oauth credentials
 ************************************************/
if (!$oauth_credentials = getOAuthCredentialsFile()) {
  echo missingOAuth2CredentialsWarning();
  return;
}
/************************************************
 * The redirect URI is to the current page, e.g:
 * http://localhost:8080/large-file-upload.php
 ************************************************/
$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($oauth_credentials);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
// add "?logout" to the URL to remove a token from the session
if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
}
/************************************************
 * If we have a code back from the OAuth 2.0 flow,
 * we need to exchange that with the
 * Google_Client::fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode()
 * function. We store the resultant access token
 * bundle in the session, and redirect to ourself.
 ************************************************/
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
  $client->setAccessToken($token);
  // store in the session also
  $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $token;
  // redirect back to the example
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
// set the access token as part of the client
if (!empty($_SESSION['upload_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  }
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
/************************************************
 * If we're signed in then lets try to upload our
 * file.
 ************************************************/
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $client->getAccessToken()) {
  /************************************************
   * We'll setup an empty 20MB file to upload.
   ************************************************/
  DEFINE("TESTFILE", 'testfile.txt');
  if (!file_exists(TESTFILE)) {
    $fh = fopen(TESTFILE, 'w');
    fseek($fh, 1024*1024*20);
    fwrite($fh, "!", 1);
    fclose($fh);
  }
  $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
  $file->name = "Big File";
  $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
  // Call the API with the media upload, defer so it doesn't immediately return.
  $client->setDefer(true);
  $request = $service->files->create($file);
  // Create a media file upload to represent our upload process.
  $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
      $client,
      $request,
      'text/plain',
      null,
      true,
      $chunkSizeBytes
  );
  $media->setFileSize(filesize(TESTFILE));
  // Upload the various chunks. $status will be false until the process is
  // complete.
  $status = false;
  $handle = fopen(TESTFILE, "rb");
  while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
    // read until you get $chunkSizeBytes from TESTFILE
    // fread will never return more than 8192 bytes if the stream is read buffered and it does not represent a plain file
    // An example of a read buffered file is when reading from a URL
    $chunk = readVideoChunk($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
    $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
  }
  // The final value of $status will be the data from the API for the object
  // that has been uploaded.
  $result = false;
  if ($status != false) {
    $result = $status;
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
function readVideoChunk ($handle, $chunkSize)
{
    $byteCount = 0;
    $giantChunk = "";
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        // fread will never return more than 8192 bytes if the stream is read buffered and it does not represent a plain file
        $chunk = fread($handle, 8192);
        $byteCount += strlen($chunk);
        $giantChunk .= $chunk;
        if ($byteCount >= $chunkSize)
        {
            return $giantChunk;
        }
    }
    return $giantChunk;
}
?>

<div class="box">
<?php if (isset($authUrl)): ?>
  <div class="request">
    <a class='login' href='<?= $authUrl ?>'>Connect Me!</a>
  </div>
<?php elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'): ?>
  <div class="shortened">
    <p>Your call was successful! Check your drive for this file:</p>
    <p><a href="https://drive.google.com/open?id=<?= $result->id ?>" target="_blank"><?= $result->name ?></a></p>
    <p>Now try <a href="/large-file-download.php">downloading a large file from Drive</a>.
  </div>
<?php else: ?>
  <form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Click here to upload a large (20MB) test file" />
  </form>
<?php endif ?>
</div>

<?= pageFooter(__FILE__) ?>
```

And for additional reference open this [So post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510014/use-google-drive-api-in-laravel-5).

You may check [this post](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/700) from github relating to login error and to retrieve the access token this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth) defined the steps needed.

The user has a login required issue when trying to insert a file in Google Drive.

This is the response.

> You'll need to grant your app access to your user account using an
>   OAuth2 authorization flow. Once you've done this, the application will
>   be granted an access token and refresh token, and will be able to
>   maintain access to your account using these.

In which you will need these general process:

> 1. When you create your application, you register it using the **Google API Console**. Google then provides information you'll need later, such as a client ID and a client secret.
> 2. Activate the Drive API in the Google API Console. (If the API isn't listed in the API Console, then skip this step.)
> 3. When your application needs access to user data, it asks Google for a particular **scope** of access.
> 4. Google displays a **consent screen** to the user, asking them to authorize your application to request some of their data.
> 5. If the user approves, then Google gives your application a short-lived access token.
> 6. Your application requests user data, attaching the **access token** to the request.
> 7. If Google determines that your request and the token are valid, it returns the requested data.